# The effect of memory barriers on data visibility to other threads

Tags: c++, c, c++11, memory-barriers

When a thread, T, reads an object at any point in time, the value it sees could be:

1. The initial value of the object.
2. A value stored by T.
3. A value stored by another thread.

And there are memory barriers (**Load-Load**, **Load-Store**, **Store-Load**, and **Store-Store**), which can be defined as:

> <**Load**s|**Store**s> *before* the barrier can't be reordered ***past*** the barrier
> and <**Load**s|**Store**s> *after* the barrier can't get reordered ***prior*** to the
> barrier.

Now, assume that a thread T1 is executing this piece of code:

```
load(X)
store(Y, 1)
-----------  <-- a barrier
load(Y)
store(X, 1)
```

while another thread, T2, is executing this piece of code:

```
load(Y)
------- <--- a barrier
load(X)
```

What would be the effect of the barriers in T1 and T2 (assume they are the same) on the visibility of X and Y in thread T2, when the barriers are:

1. Load-Load
2. Load-Store
3. Store-Load
4. Store-Store

Thanks!

Comment: You don't choose a program based on the barrier. You choose a barrier based on the program. What is the programming problem you're having? This so far is a theoretical question about computer memory architecture. For example, "I wrote this program, but I'm concerned about memory barriers. What is the correct barrier to use here?"

Comment: Depending on the type of the object and the characteristics of the machine, your 3 possibilities in the first paragraph could be accompanied by "4. Something completely different."  E.g., for a type that isn't atomic.

Comment: Since T2 has no barriers, the barrier in T1 has no effect on T2.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE thanks! I will modify the question a bit.

Comment: My answer on your newer question ([memory\_order\_relaxed and visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128464)) may shed some light on this: barriers just order this core's access to coherent shared memory.  They can't make other cores wait for this core's stores.